# Определить есть ли данная книга в наличии на пунктах выдачи

Tags: sql-server

Создать доп. атрибут НАЛИЧИЕ в табл. КНИГА или можно в запросе отсортировать как нибудь? Пытался объединить КНИГА и ВЫДАЧА ничего толкового не вышло...

```
select название, count(КНИГА.код_книги) as кол_во

from dbo.Выдача
INNER JOIN dbo.Книга ON dbo.Выдача.код_книги = dbo.Книга.код_книги

where дата_возврата < getdate() and факт_возврат is not null
GROUP BY название
```

[image: Диаграмма БД]

Comment: Добавьте код Вашей попытки в вопрос. Просто без него он выглядит в стиле "сделайте за меня". Без обид.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Вы проектируете базу или пытаетесь по готовой базе создать запрос? Если спроектировать, то архтиектура так себе, если создать запрос, то непонятно, что вызывает вопрос.

Comment: И, не надо в заголовке дублировать метки. [Подробнее тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/607/213987)

Comment: Проектирую базу и по ней делю запросы. Хотел бы еще тогда узнать проблемы в архитектуре бд

Comment: Если проектируете базу, то это вопрос длинный и сразу уходит в такую вещь, как проектирование складов, расчёт остатков и т.п. У вас должны быть товары, склады, а приложение должно делать проводки, такие как "поступления", "списание" и прочее. Ключевая ошибка тут вот какая: вы всё это пытаетесь сделать расчётами, на лету. Обычно есть процедура закрытия дня, когда рассчитываются остатки по всем складам по всему миру (миллионы товаров!), часть базы уходит на отдельные сервера-только-для-чтения (аналитика), а в новом дне работают с остатками.

Comment: Так как делаете вы... через год накопится столько выдач-покупок-возвратов, что запросы начнут тормозить, их нужно будет выносить во вьюхи... Понимаете, хорошо спроектированное приложение не нужно переделывать каждые пару месяцев, когда что-то забилось. А у вас архитектура именно поэтому и неудобна: за приложением постоянно нужен будет присмотр разработчиков.

Comment: у меня это пока курсовая)

Comment: @egorusakov вы лучше потратьте время и добавьте описание задачи со всеми допущениями и ограничениями, что бы было понятно насколько детально вы собираетесь прорабатывать и предметную область, иначе очень сложно найти недочеты в вашей архитектуре.

Comment: и лучше начать обсуждение в чате

Answer (score 0):

Одна книга может находиться в нескольких пунктах выдачи и один пункт выдачи может содержать несколько книг. Тут связь N-N нужна. Сейчас же книге присваивается пункт выдачи, причем нет информации об остатках книг. 
Сделайте промежуточную таблицу, реализующую N-N  с полями:

```
код_книги
код_пункта
остаток
```